# Accessing a report, where report name is a variable

Tags: vba, ms-access, office365

This is possibly a very easy question but I haven't found any obvious answer online to this.

I need to back-engineer an Access Database and have it save the data to a file. At present it sends this report to a printer.

There is a button which reads the report name from a dropdown.
What I want to do is pass this report name as a parameter, get the record source of the report and send that to a file.

At the moment I have this  - which works but is hardcoded:

```
DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , "name of the query", "C:\temp\name of a file_.csv" & TheDate & ".csv", False
```

What I would like to do is something like this....

```
VQueryReportName = Vmyrs("txt_QueryReportName")
VQueryReportName = Replace(VQueryReportName, Chr(34), vbNullString)

QueryName = Reports![VQueryReportName].RecordSource

DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , QueryName, "C:\temp\filename.csv", False
```

I have validated that VQueryReportName does contain the correct name for the report.
The error I get is:

[image]

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the value of the variable:

```
QueryName = Reports(VQueryReportName).RecordSource
```

But the report must be open for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than getting the Recordsource of an (open) report, consider creating a lookup table that has the name of the report in on field, and the query that it is based on in another field. You can then set the source of a combo box to be based on this table, and then get the query name this way.

Regards,